# requestAlwaysAuthorization after requestWhenInUseAuthorization is accepted

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

My app can have two level of LocationHandler status. First, I launch `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and then, if the user activates some specific features, I launch `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

I need to be notified if user refuses the requestAlwaysAuthorization to let him know the feature won't work as expected. The problem is that in this case `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` is not called because the authorization status stays the same (it was `AuthorizedWhenInUse` and it's still `AuthorizedWhenInUse`).

Do you have any idea how I could be notified if user refuses AuthorizedAlways after accepting AuthorizedWhenInUse ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since iOS 10 or so it is no longer possible to call requestAlwaysAuthorization() after you have called requestWhenInUseAuthorization() even if the user accepted when-in-use.

in prior versions (at least iOS8) you could "step up" the authorization and ask for always-authorization after the user accepted when-in-use. This is no longer possible.

best thing to do is check CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
 once in a while and show a dialog pointing the user to the right settings page with UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString